# Multiple mouse clicks required to select ListViewItem

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2019

I have a NavigationViewItem that contains a ListView item that sits inside a ScrollViewer. When the NavigationViewItem is originally displayed 4 mouse clicks are required to select any of the items displayed in the ListView. Using the FocusTracker developer tool I can see that the first mouse click sets focus to the ScrollViewer (although the ScrollViewer does not display since there are only a couple of ListViewItems in my ListView). The FocusTracker shows that the next 2 mouse clicks return focus to the NavigationViewItem. However, on the second of these 2 mouse clicks (i.e., the 3rd mouse click) the background of the ListViewItem that I am clicking changes to the mouse over color. Only on the 4th mouse click is that item actually selected and the SelectionChanged event fired.

I have tried setting focus on the ListView, using the focus method, once the page has been loaded but it does not work (i.e., the ListView does not receive focus).

I would like for the ListViewItem.SelectionChanged event to be fired after the first mouse click but have not figured out anyway to make this happen.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us your code?

Comment: This is my question on stackoverflow. I tried copying some code into this reply but it was too long. Is there another way to share.

Comment: You could share [mcve] with github or one drive.